# How to populate a hashmap with the keys in one set and the values in another set

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, hashmap, set

I am using the Property object and I have the following:

```
m_Properties.stringPropertyNames() //A set of Strings that I want to use as the key

m_Properties.values() //A set of Strings that I want to use as the value
```

I want to put them in this hashmap

```
 private static HashMap<String, String> newProperties = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

I am not sure as I would have to loop through both at the same time, but how would I do that?

Comment: I don't think that Set is the right Collection because it is not ordered. Try to use List instead of set. When you use List you can do easy for cycle with `m_Properties.values().get(int index)` method.

Comment: m_Properties.stringPropertyNames() and m_Properties.values()  - do they have the same number of elements? And you to want put each [i] element of the first collection and each [i] element of the second collection into hashmap, right?

Comment: They do have the same number of elements and yes  i do

Comment: Why do you want to do this mapping from those two sets, instead of directly from the `Properties` object (which is already a `HashTable` and implements a `Map`)?

Answer (score 1):

Ugly ancient object....

```
for(String property : m_Properties.stringPropertyNames()) {
    newProperties.put(property, m_properties.getProperty(property));
}
```